# How to find number of times record is accessed for oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have oracle 10g database in my application. How to find out that how many times the a particular records has been accessed in particular table.

Comment: You can't find that out.

Comment: @juergend can I find whether any record is not accessed at all?

Comment: I doubt it. You would need to implement that in your program logic.

Comment: @juergend , ohhh m java person not dba ... but can i find when the record is inserted in database using any sql query.

Comment: If you add a column in your table that contains the insert date then yes. You can set a default for any column. If you leave it empty while inserting then the DB will use the default value. Use the current time as default value and the DB will insert that automatically.

Comment: @juergend tat was gr8 help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, to do that, you need to access records in a table though stored procedure, not through SELECT statement.

But, here is how it could be simplified:

1. you add a requirement that any SELECT to your table should have a function call:

   ```
   select yourtable.* from yourtable
   where yourfunct('yourtable', yourtable.key) = 'done'
   ```

   this could be easily done through view plus revoking permissions to read the table itself
2. in your function, you either save table/key pair inside a table in a package (you don't need to start a transaction to do that) or you start an autonomous transaction and write into a real table.

   writing into a variable in a package is not thead safe, but it is much faster.

   creating a transaction is slooooooower, but it will garantie a result.

My personal preference would be to question an original task. Maybe it would be enough to create sort of 'log entry' table where requests for data are recorded.

Comment: #1 could potentially be automated by using [virtual private database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/vpd.htm#DBSEG007).  VPD allows a function to return a predicate designed to control access.  That function could always return true but have a side-affect of recording the access request.  But I doubt it's possible to ever record all access with 100% accuracy, nobody really knows exactly how many times parts of a SQL statement will run.  VPD would only be good enough for a rough estimate.